# What are the scars on the face of Dryden Voss?

Tags: star-wars, solo-a-star-wars-story

Dryden Voss, the iconic villain in *Solo: A Star Wars Story*, has some pretty radical facial scarring.

[image: Dryden Voss, facing right 3/4, showing prominent blotchy red streaks on his cheek and forehead]

I'm wondering if there is any evidence how he got these scars?

In particular is it possible he got the scars in battle, or from exposure to a particular substance or drug.

It also seems he is under the service of a Sith Lord (if not an apprentice himself) and if so, could this have come as part of an initiation into, or training with, the dark arts.

Answer (score 11):

They are just what his species looks like. Paul Bettany, the actor of Dryden Voss, was asked this on Twitter and the verified Star Wars account has [tweeted](https://twitter.com/starwars/status/995461999621324801) a video of Paul's response (transcript below).

> Hey Ethan, well they're not actually scars. I think they are just his species. I think that the other members of his species will have the same markings that flush red when they get furious.

---

His "species" is shown as "near-human" in *Solo - A Star Wars Story - The Official Guide*. So, in essence his actual species is not known, as "near-human" is a classification of a species rather than an actual species.

[image: Solo - A Star Wars Story - The Official Guide, Dryden Voss Data File]

Comment: Which species is that? And do they have any other aspects, like super agility or strength (after watching him fight, I wondered)

Comment: @vikingsteve I haven't seen the film so don't know about that, would probably deserve a question of it's own. Will check to see what species he is, that seems to be in scope to the question and answer.

Comment: And now there’s [a question asking about his species](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/189903/13217).

Answer (score 10):

The film's [Official Guide](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Solo:_A_Star_Wars_Story_The_Official_Guide) indicates that the striation on his face is

> linked to **circulatory system activity and adrenaline levels**.

No further specifics are offered.

[image: Headshot of Voss showing the lines on his face; a leader line connects one to a bubble which reads "Striation linked to circulatory system activity and adrenaline levels"]

Comment: I read that page to get the data file image, how did I miss that? +1

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - I was debating whether to just prod you :-)