# What species is Dryden Voss?

Tags: star-wars, solo-a-star-wars-story

As described in the answers to [What are the scars on the face of Dryden Voss?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/189900/13217), his face is not actually scarred but is rather the way that his species looks.

What species is Dryden Voss?

Comment: So basically what's going to be answered in that question? Spoiler alert, [Not known](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dryden_Vos)

Comment: I've edited this into my answer on the previous question as I believe it is within scope there. I don't see the need for a separate question.